# Finding the realpath of a file in unix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I have the following code, which is expected to do the following,

- Directory name (dirName) and a prefix is provided as input to the function.
- Lists out all the contents one level down from the provided input directory (dirName) and starts populating the file details within the sub directories using the os.walk function.
- Once the files are found they are checked against a specific prefix and processed further.
- The motive is that once a file is identified (which satisfies a prefix), I want the absolute realpath of that file. I tried using the Path(libfile).resolve() option but its giving only the present working directory from where the script is run as against the realpath of that file. Could you explain where I am going wrong?

  ```
  import os
  from pathlib import Path

  def directory(dirName, prefix):

  process_dir = [name for name in os.listdir(dirName) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dirName, name))]
  for entry in process_dir:
      for dirname, directory, files in os.walk(os.path.join(dirName, entry)):
          for libfile in files:
              if libfile.startswith((prefix)):
                  return(Path(libfile).resolve())
  ```

Python version 3.6.2.

Comment: I am using python 3.6.2

Comment: Take a look at the value of `libfile` and it should be immediately obvious why python can't find the absolute path of it. It's a file name. There could be 5 million files with that name on your file system. How is python supposed to know which one you meant?

Comment: yes libfile is a file name and I want the complete realpath of that. My understanding was the Path function should be able to resolve the realpath of a file in python

Comment: @wim, what is MCVE?

Comment: So, what's the realpath of the file name `foo.txt`?

Comment: I get it now, looks like my implementation is wrong then. Ok given the need is there a way to better modify the code to get the required output (ie., I want the realpath of the files which satisfies the criterion)

Comment: You need to join the parts together for `libfile` before you call resolve. Use `dirname` for the relative path.

Comment: You can also use `pathlib` to replace `os.walk` with a recursive glob pattern. It is a little more seamless if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
return(Path(libfile).resolve())
```

To this:

```
return (Path(dirname) / libfile).resolve()
```

I agree with [the comment from dawg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991764/finding-the-realpath-of-a-file-in-unix/51991967#comment90933375_51991764) that using a recursive glob pattern would be a better choice here.

Comment: thanks a lot for all the comments/suggestion and help. It resolved my issue. For curiosity could anyone also list the solution with glob that was suggested by dawg?

Answer (score 2):

Several issues:

1) You are returning only a single file

2) You are calling `.resolve` with only a file name, so where the path will be resolved depends on the current working directory.

3) Your spec states that you only want to descend one level in the directory tree but you are not pruning the descent path that `os.walk` is taking.

I suggest ditching `os.walk` and fully using `Path`.

You state that only want the files from one level down; that means you need to walk that level with `Path`:

```
file_names=[]
for d in (p for p in Path(dirName).glob('*') if p.is_dir()):
    ab_path=d.resolve()
    file_names+=[fn for fn in Path(ab_path).iterdir() if fn.is_file() and fn.name.startswith(prefix)]

return file_names
```

It is also possible to construct a glob pattern that will simplify that further. It may be as easy as:

```
Path(dirName).glob('*/prefix*')
```

Or,

```
[p.resolve() for p in Path(dirName).glob('*/prefix*') if p.is_file()]
```

to find the files one directory down with the prefix you seek.